# Updating Database using Csv File

Tags: php, csv

When i upload the Csv file it always says Incorrect Table ".

I checked the Table name and it was correct
but i still dont know why it isn't updating the database.
It is possible to update the database using Csv files? or only inserting is possible?

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$modname = $user_data['name'];
$usy = $_POST['usy'];
$usem = $_POST['usem'];
$term2 = $_POST['term2'];
if ( isset( $_FILES['userfile'] ) )
{
  $csv_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

  if ( ! is_file( $csv_file ) )
    exit('File not found.');



  if (($handle = fopen( $csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE)
  {
      fgetcsv($handle); // get line 0 and move pointer to line 1
      fgetcsv($handle); // get line 1 and move pointer to line 2
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
      {  
        {
        $sql = "UPDATE `$term2` SET grade = $data[1] WHERE name_id = $data[0], section = $data[4], subject = $data[5], uploaded = $modname, school_year = $usy , semester = $usem"; 
        $exec = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $sql2 = "DELETE FROM `$term2` WHERE `name_id` = '' AND `grade` = '';";  
        $exec = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());   

        echo ("The following data has been added to the database");
        }
      }
    }
  }
?>
<form name="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
    <H1>Update CSV File</H1>
    School Year:<input type="text" name="usy"> Semester:    <select type="text" name="usem">
    <option value="1st">1st</option>
    <option value="2nd">2nd</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    Term:       <select type="text" name="term2">
    <option value="prelims">Prelims</option>
    <option value="midterm">Midterm</option>
    <option value="prefinals">Prefinals</option>
    <option value="finals">Finals</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input name="userfile" type="file">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">



        </form>
```

Comment: Show us a sample query

Comment: id/name/section/subject/grade/uploaded/school_year/semester
1/sample/samplesec/samplesub/80/sampleprof/2013-2014/1st

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are making error in your sql statement

```
$sql = "UPDATE `$term2` SET grade = $data[1] WHERE name_id = $data[0], section = $data[4], subject = $data[5], uploaded = $modname, school_year = $usy , semester = $usem";
```

The WHERE clause must have either AND/OR in place of comma(,) for adding conditions. Comma should be used to separate columns/fields that you want to set through the update.

Comment: please give me your corrected sql. You also have to put the values within the single quotes.

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE `$term2` SET grade = $data[1] WHERE name_id = $data[0] AND section = $data[4] AND subject = $data[5] AND uploaded = $modname AND school_year = $usy AND semester = $usem";

Comment: Put string values within single quotes in your sql. So, modify your sql as - $sql = "UPDATE $term2 SET grade = '$data[1]' WHERE name_id = $data[0] AND section = '$data[4]' AND subject = '$data[5]' AND uploaded = '$modname' AND school_year = '$usy' AND semester = '$usem' ";   I am assuming that name_id is of number type.

Comment: yep Name_id is the Id type
Tried it and still it gives the Incorrect Table name " error

Comment: Could you please send the echo of your sql that is - echo $sql; I feel that really there is error in the name of your table.

Comment: I tried echoing it out still it give the incorrect table name error
but the name of the table is prelims where $term2 = prelims

Comment: comment both the // $exec statement and try with echoing the sql statements. This might help you in getting the actual issue in the sql statement. Try it : echo '<br/>'. $sql = "UPDATE `$term2` SET grade = $data[1] WHERE name_id = $data[0], section = $data[4], subject = $data[5], uploaded = $modname, school_year = $usy , semester = $usem"; 
        //$exec = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        echo '<br/>'.$sql2 = "DELETE FROM `$term2` WHERE `name_id` = '' AND `grade` = '';";  
        //$exec = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());   
Try running these sql in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

You have one flaw in your query:
"$sql = "UPDATE `$term2` SET grade = $data[1] WHERE..."
Remove the $ from `$term2`, it should read:
"$sql = "UPDATE `term2` SET grade = $data[1] WHERE..."